# Java in usr/bin/java missing

Tags: java

I can locate java in my machine in **etc/alternatives/java**(link to executable file to **/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java** where I can see executable java file). 
Kindly please help me to move this java file to usr/bin/java directory.
As lot of dependant applications are failing to run because of this.

Thanks
Pritam

Comment: Then just create symbolic link in `/usr/bin` for `java` that points to the actual location

Comment: search for unix's cp command or ln -s to create a symlink

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Kindly help me with steps

Comment: I can see symlink is now created after using **ln -s**, but when I am trying to run the dependant application, I get an error which says : line 25: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the setup you are looking for.  I am surprised that the install process didn't do this for you. You need the Unix `ln -s` command.

```
$ file /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/java
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 18  2018 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

Comment: I can see symlink is now created after using ln -s, but when I am trying to run the dependant application, I get an error which says : line 25: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

This is because there are some 32-bit libraries missing in your Ubuntu 64-bit. Run:

```
apt-get install libc6-i386
```